# Need to enable SSL handshake log in Opensearch 1.2

Tags: opensearch

I am doing POC around OpenSearch1.3 by enabling SSL with self signed certificte but getting SSL Exception.I tried going throgh Opensearch DOC but found no relavent content . Please help if there is any way to enable SSL logs .
*javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown*

Comment: I have solved this issue..We need to open file <opensearch_install_dir>/config/jvm.options and add a line as -Djavax.net.debug=all and restart service